# I am trying to call a function that I manually created in Python & saved in the lib directory. How can I do this?

Tags: python, function, directory

I created a Binary Search Function in Python, and saved it as a .py file to the lib directory associated with Python Idle. How can I successfully call this function after importing it?

I receive an error when trying to call the function after adding parameters.

Error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
  from lib import BinarySearch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

EDIT: Using Windows 10, error I receive after correcting import statement:

```
import BinarySearch
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
  BinarySearch()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `BinarySearch.py in`.../Pythonxy/Lib`(to use the Windows name), use`import BinarySearch`, just like you would use`import abc`for`Lib/abc.py`and so on for other built-in modules in`/Lib`.

[It would generally be better to call the file `binary_search.py` and reserve CamelCase names for classes.  It would also be better to put your files in `Lib/site-packages` or in a directory in your user directory.  But these are other issues.]

None of this has anything in particular to do with IDLE as such.

Edit: Now that you can import the module, you must call the function within the module.  If the function is also called `BinarySearch`:

```
BinarySearch.BinarySearch()
```

or

```
from BinarySearch import BinarySearch  # import the function from the module
BinarySearch()
```

I presume, though, that the function needs an argument or two.

[It would be less confusing if the module and function have different names, such as module `binsearch` (file `binsearch.py`) and function `binary_search`.]

Comment: I am able to import it, but I am not able to call it after importing it. I receive, "The module callback is not callable"

Comment: Edit the original question to say what OS are you using.  Show the import statement and the resulting traceback, copied and pasted, then formatted as code.

Comment: Ok, I changed it. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: You were supposed to edit your question, not my answer.  I took what you tried to add to my answer and added it to your question, and will add to my answer.